# Unable to remove a polygon from Bing map

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a screen in my application from where I am managing the polygons and information related to polygons using Bing map.

I wanted to display the polygon details when somebody clicks on the polygons. So I added a click event on the polygons and its working fine.

I also want to allow user to edit the polygon while viewing/modifying the other information after click event. So I planned to remove the polygon after click event from map's entities and add it to drawing manager for further edition. However I am not able to remove a particular polygon from map's entities. I tried preparing the same polygon and pass it to map's entities remove function but its not working. Below is sample code for same and my application is developed in angular:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
});

var polygon1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude - 0.03),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude - 0.11),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.05, center.longitude - 0.07)
]);
polygon1.entity = { id: 1 };
map.entities.push(polygon1);

var polygon2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude + 0.03),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude + 0.11),
    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.05, center.longitude + 0.07)
]);
polygon2.entity = { id: 2 };
map.entities.push(polygon2);    

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon, 'click', function (e) {   
    var geoId = e.target.entity.id;
    //Here I want to find the polygon with provided Id and remove it so that I can add it to drawing manager for further modification
    //Code to remove the polygon
    var polygonToRemove = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude - 0.03),
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.01, center.longitude - 0.11),
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(center.latitude + 0.05, center.longitude - 0.07)
    ]);
    polygonToRemove.entity = { id: 1 };
    map.entities.remove(polygonToRemove);
    //Code to add the polygon to drawing manager
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click event handler you are creating a new polygon which may have the same locations as another polygon, but is a different object none the less. You have to pass in an instance of the actual shape object you want removed not a copy of it. Here is a modified version of your code:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon, 'click', function (e) {   
    map.entities.remove(e.target);
});
```

Comment: Thank you rbrundritt. I am able to remove the polygons now. Also just wanted to know, if I want to find an entity/polygon from entitycollection using entity.id and then remove it. How can I do it?

Comment: Loop through all the shapes in the collection and check the property value until you find the shape you are looking for, then use the remove function of the collection and break out of the loop. 

Instead of adding an entity property to shapes, use the metadata property. The Bing Maps API has specifically reserved the metadata property name for developers so they can add custom metadata such as an id to a shape without risk of the Bing Maps team using this name and  breaking apps. The entity property name is used by the Bing Maps team and there could be issues with using this in the future.